# removing columns from a file on my database

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of tab delimited files on my database that have 7 columns with the headers 'name', 'taxID', 'taxRank', 'genomesize', 'numReads', 'numUniqueReads', 'abundance'. I would like to write a program that will call in a file generically (like using sys.argv) to bring in one file at a time and keep columns 0,1,4 (name, taxID, & numReads). I'm trying (very poorly) to do this in Python.

```
with open (sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    rows =  ( line.split('\t') for line in f)
    d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    sys.argv[1]_prekrona = df.drop(['taxRank','genomesize','numUniqueReads','abundance'], axis = 1)
```

After running the script I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "open_file.py", line 19, in <module>
    df.drop(['taxRank','genomesize','numUniqueReads','abundance'], axis = 1)
  File "/software/7/apps/python_3/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3697, in drop
    errors=errors)
  File "/software/7/apps/python_3/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3108, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "/software/7/apps/python_3/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3140, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "/software/7/apps/python_3/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4388, in drop
    'labels %s not contained in axis' % labels[mask])
KeyError: "labels ['taxRank' 'genomesize' 'numUniqueReads' 'abundance'] not contained in axis"
```

This tells me I have to define my columns, but I am not sure how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you print the output of `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: Can you explain how this is a pandas question?

Comment: @tdelozie I was googling how to do this and most suggested using a pandas dataframe, so that's why it's a pandas question, but I'm very new to this so any suggestions are welcome

Comment: instead of drop use sys.argv[1]_prekrona = df[['name', 'taxID', 'numReads']] naming the columns you want to keep; you should also look into using pd.read_csv() if they are delimited text files. the real problem is that you might not be reading in headers. df.columns will show you want the headers really are.

Comment: @JonathanLeon will read_csv read in any text file and not just a csv? I'm very new to all of this, so genuinely curious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols = ["name", "taxID", "numReads"]
```

`usecols` will take a list of column headers and create a subset of the data using only those columns.

Comment: Hi! I really like that idea, but will it work on a file that's already on my database and is tab delimited rather than a csv? Thank you!

Comment: the above solution is a good suggestion. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html  Look at the docs and set your sep argument for tab, or try without and read_csv will try to infer what it is.